# Как уменьшить фото до конкретного размера на php

Tags: php

Есть код который вырезает участок фото по выбору пользователя, теперь надо то что он выбрал довести до квадратика 60*60px (фото из которого это будет делаться имеет размер 1/1 (квадрат) тупо надо уменьшить и закачать после уменьшения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция для изменения размера до необходимого, измените под себя, если необходимо. Работает через библиотеку GD.

$neww- новая ширина

$newh - новая высота

```
function imageresize($outfile,$infile,$neww,$newh,$quality) 
{

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg($infile);
$im1=imagecreatetruecolor($neww,$newh);
imagecopyresampled($im1, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $neww, $newh, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

imagejpeg($im1,$outfile,$quality);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($im1);
}

imageresize("images/file.jpg","webcam.jpg",320,240,75);
```